# vagrant with multiple sync'd folders

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to set more than one sync'd folder in a vagrantfile? Here's my current config (using `vaprobash`):

```
# Use NFS for the shared folder
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/Sites",
          id: "core",
          :nfs => true,
          :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

# Use NFS for the shared folder
config.vm.synced_folder "../Code", "/vagrant/Code",
          id: "core",
          :nfs => true,
          :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
```

Only the second mapping gets loaded, the other is ignored-- so I end up with a `/vagrant/Code` directory mapped properly, but no `vagrant/Sites`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**2021 Update:**

In 2021 no need for unique Id or being `nfs`, just list your synced folders:

```yaml
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/Sites"
config.vm.synced_folder "../Code", "/vagrant/Code"
```

---

**Original answer:**

I just needed to set a unique ID for each mount, and then reload the vagrant box.

```
# Use NFS for the shared folder
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/Sites",
      id: "sites", # <--- this ID must be unique
      :nfs => true,
      :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

# Use NFS for the shared folder
config.vm.synced_folder "../Code", "/vagrant/Code",
      id: "code", # <--- different from this one
      :nfs => true,
      :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
```